# Css prefixer module for Python?

Tags: python

Such [prefixer library](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer)  exists for JS, it allows to prefix CSS content with vendor prefixes. Does same / similar module exist for Python? I'd want to use it in Py3.

Comment: What are you using now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. The library is named [`cssprefixer`](https://github.com/myfreeweb/cssprefixer). You can install it from pypi using `pip install cssprefixer`.

You could also consider using [`webassets`](http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which includes a filter that invokes cssprefixer.